# left outer join sql 2012

Tags: sql

I have made two tables: one with 5 columns and the other with 3 columns.
By using left outer join I want my resultant table to show all 5 columns of first table along with just first column of second table. any solution?
It shows all 3 columns of second table but I want it to show just one.

Comment: Post the query. Wild guess is that you are using `SELECT *` when you should be specifying columns in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: yes am using select *. I should be naming all the columns in select statement?

Comment: You should be naming the ones you want to return.  `SELECT *` is handy for prototyping but should not usually be used in production code.  `SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col5, t2.col1 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT *` always shows *all* columns from all tables in the query.

If you want a subset of these, you have to be more specific.  Example:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.column1
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ...
```

Comment: Using * gives error saying table name does not match with any column in this query, may be because I was executing it in new query. but mentioning each column with table name solves the problem though.

Comment: This is my school assignment, I am asked to join both tables with left out join so what you suggest is best way to join?

Comment: If they asked you to use left outer join, then use left outer join.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.FirstColumnName
FROM T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN T2
    ON T1.Id = T2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
create table dbo.Alpha
(
  id int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered ,
  A  int not null ,
  B  int not null ,
  C  int not null ,
)
create table dbo.Bravo
(
  id       int not null identity(1,1) primary key clustered  ,
  Alpha_ID int     null foreign key references dbo.Alpha(id) ,
  A        int not null ,
  B        int not null ,
  C        int not null ,
)

select a.* , -- all colulmns from the first table
       b.A , -- specific columns from the second table
       b.B   -- specific columns from the second table
from      dbo.Alpha a
left join dbo.Bravo b on b.Alpha_ID = a.id
```